# Random string generated characters not in original string

Tags: php, random

I use the following script to generate a temporary password.

**before** I get a lecture, I AM aware that this isn't crypto secure, and that I should use something like openssl_random_pseudo_bytes. But my question is not regarding 'being secure'.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!£$%^&*()?';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

I used PHPMailer connected to gmail SMTP to email the password to the user. The problem I have is that when my boss did a demonstration of this whilst in another country, the following characters were sent as the temp pw:

`New Password: Il%KÂUyÂ?F`

notice the accented A's are not in my string of selectable chars. This has only happened once, however shouldn't happen at all. As a result of this - the relevant hashes didn't match either, and so the temporary password didn't work. I'm using `password_hash($string, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` with field length of 255.

Surely the fact that he was in a different country when he tested the function shouldn't have any bearing on the chars sent seeing as they are generated from the server, which obviously has a static location.

```
$key = generateRandomString();
$msg.="New Password: ".$key."<br><br>";
$mail->Body = $msg;
```

Comment: No, but a charset might depending on how the data was being displayed

Comment: Can you shed more light on this? The data was displayed in an email (ms exchange outlook). I have looked in the actual gmail sentbox, and the chars exist in there, so it must be something between php and the email that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried it myself and the function works perfectly, so I think your problem is about encoding.

First of all make sure your string is UTF-8 encoded, using

```
utf8_encode($key);
```

You can use mb_detect_encoding on $msg and $key to check it just to be sure.
If you still have problems try:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

PHPmailer can be a pain with encoding sometimes.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice one, thanks very much! I still don't understand why it actually happened, though!